# Why isn't my if function targeting the "timer" variable? I am trying to get it to alert/console "time is up" when the timer hits 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me know if anyone has any ideas.  I hope I don't get to much hate for this but I have been playing around with this for a while and it isn't working for me.`

```
function countdown() {
    timer = 20;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        timer--;
        console.log(timer);
        $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();

if(timer == 0) {
    console.log("Time is up");
    alert("Time is up!");
    incorrect ++;
    $(".list-group").hide();
    $(".Game").hide();
    $(".timer").hide();
    $(".timer").reset();
    $(".Photo1").show();
}
```

Comment: Do you want stop the interval when `timer==0`?

Comment: I think that you have 4 good answers about how to alert *"Time is up!"*... You should make a choice... If your concern is more about *why* than *how*, that's another thing. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your "timeup" code into the interval.

```
function countdown() {
    timer = 20;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        timer--;
        console.log(timer);
        $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
        if(timer == 0) {
            console.log("Time is up");
            alert("Time is up!");
            incorrect ++;
            $(".list-group").hide();
            $(".Game").hide();
            $(".timer").hide();
            $(".timer").reset();
            $(".Photo1").show();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

create a function to check the timer variable in every intervals

```
var timer, timerId ;
function countdown() {
    timer = 20;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        timer--;
        console.log(timer);
        $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
        check();//call check function in every intervals
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
function check(){
    if(timer == 0) {
      clearTimeout(timerId );//clear timer function
      console.log("Time is up");
      alert("Time is up!");
      incorrect ++;
      $(".list-group").hide();
      $(".Game").hide();
      $(".timer").hide();
      $(".timer").reset();
      $(".Photo1").show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then to achieve this you'll want to move the logic that triggers your `alert("Time is up!");` and `console.log()` behaviour into the interval callback as follows:

```js
function countdown() {

    var timer = 20;
    var incorrect = 0;

    var timerId = setInterval(function() {

        timer--;
        console.log(timer);

        $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
        
        // place alert and console log logic here 
        // so that it is run when timer equals zero
        if(timer === 0) {
            
            console.log("Time is up");
            alert("Time is up!");
            incorrect ++;
            $(".list-group").hide();
            $(".Game").hide();
            $(".timer").hide();
            $(".timer").reset();
            $(".Photo1").show();
        }
        
    }, 1000);
}

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the *timer* variable inside `countdown()` and use `clearInterval()` to stop the time like the following way:

```js
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
var timer = 20;
var incorrect = 0;
function countdown() { 
    timer--;
    console.log(timer);
    //$(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
    
    if(timer == 0) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      console.log("Time is up");
      //alert("Time is up!");
      incorrect ++;
      /*$(".list-group").hide();
      $(".Game").hide();
      $(".timer").hide();
      $(".timer").reset();
      $(".Photo1").show();*/
  }
}

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```